# How to use dynamic rules in Drools loading from a database

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, drools

Does anyone have any idea how to load dynamic rules from a database to be used in Drools.

My requirement is to give the business users the full flexibility to define rules as per their requirement while not modifying any source codes. I'm using `Spring Boot 2.0.2` and `Drools 7`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this.

1. You can use Drools Workbench to store, build rules and then retrieve them via your application code.
2. You can store Drools rules file in a folder locally and retrieve them via your application code.

But both requires periodic refresh of the KieBase.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already created a sample Spring Boot project and configured it to use a drl file. And it is working. Now what I want is to find a way to dynamically add rules without changing the source code. I have read some articles about rule templates but I couldn't find any solution except this [Drools Rules in a Database](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2013/03/jboss-rules-in-database-take-2.html). But the problem with this source code is, it is written in Scala. Could you please point me to a direction where I can find a sample source code in Java.

Comment: Did you look at Drools Workbench? It sounds that it is exactly what you need.